# How can I calculate confidence level of my ML Model for each Image of ResNet9

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I made the ML Model using the Resnet9 algorithm. In this model, I have 38 classes.
After the prediction, It returns the tuple like this:

[image]

It is returning negative values. In the above case, the highest value is -204.0966 means it has the highest chance of being the correct one.

I want to make it in percentage to see what the confidence(Accuracy) of that image. If anyone wants to see the code please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the softmax function, which maps vector values to values that sum to 1 (it's a way to get a probability distribution) and multiplies the result by 100 to get percentages:

```
import torch
torch.nn.functional.softmax(model_output) * 100
```

[Softmax @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)

Comment: Can You explain to me what did you do in the above code?

Comment: Yes, I applied the *softmax* function which basically maps a vector values to values that sum to 1 (it's a way to get a probability ditribution) and multiplied the result by 100 to get percentages. Check softmax it is really useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function